# AngularJS - Set/Reset timeout when a user is typing in any field inside a form

Tags: angularjs

I want to do autosave, that will be fired after user's inactivity (3 second). By inactivity I mean that he won't be typing (input), selecting any options (select), clicking radio buttons etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using **ngModelOptions** you can specify a custom list of events that will trigger a model update and/or a **debouncing** delay so that the actual update only takes place when a timer expires; this timer will be reset after another change takes place.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example35-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="debounceExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 3000 }" /><br />
  </form>
  <pre>username = "{{user.name}}"</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('debounceExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

may be this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JjxlfW0fEoBWZzSM5GCp?p=preview) will help uh.. try this... here, the model field will be updated after   3 sec delay and the error check will occur afterwards...

Comment: Nice I didn't know of this feature. Can you include a link of documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a timeout and reset it after the user edits something:

```
.controller("myCtrl", [
    "$timeout",
    function ($timeout) {
        var vm = this,
            saveTime = 3000;

        var saveTimeout;

        function resetTimeout () {
            if(saveTimeout)
                saveTimeout.cancel();

            saveTimeout = $timeout(function () {
                myFactory.save(vm.myModel);
            }, saveTime);
        }

        $scope.$watch("vm.myModel", function () {
            resetTimeout();
        });

        resetTimeout();
    }]);
```